# Spinner, как в Honeycomb(3.0) для предыдущих версий (2.1+)

Tags: android, android-spinner

Нужен спиннер, который бы открывался выпадающим списком, а не диалогом. На версиях Андроида 4+ это обеспечивается атрибутом `android:spinnerMode="dropdown"`.  
Знаю, что есть что-то похожее в ActionBarSherlock, но его я использовать не могу, т. к. использую AppCompat, с которым ActionBarSherlock не совместим.

Comment: ActionBarSherlock больше не нужен же. Зачем вы его используете? Только ради 2.1-2.3?

Comment: @Suvitruf, я же написал, что в ActionBarSherlock есть нужный(скорее всего) класс.Вроде как-то так: ICSSpinner. Мне сам ActionBarSherlock не нужен. Но у ActionBarSherlock конфликтуют ресурсы с AppCompat.

Comment: Он вроде как есть в AppCompat https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/jb-mr2-release/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/SpinnerICS.java ? Или он не работает на старых версиях?

Comment: @Suvitruf, в последних версиях его уже нет. Есть другой - SpinnerCompat. Но его использовать пока у меня не получается, у него похоже нету какого-то нужного конструктора.